# I am trying to set up mariadb on a raspberry pi and keep getting an error message

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian, mariadb

The error that I keep receiving is:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-XXe4L1/1-mariadb-server-10.0_10.0.28-2+b1_armhf.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I run the command

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server-10.0
```

I used to be able to log into mariadb, and now it won't let me log in and even enter mysql safe mode, so that I can change my root@localhost password.

I ran

```
sudo cat /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

and received the output

```
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = 
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = 
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```

So I went into the file and added a password for both positions and I am still having difficulties executing the command to allow me into mariadb

I then ran `ps -ef` Like the first suggestion bellow and am not sure what process needs to be halted.  Here is the lengthy list. Can someone please guide me to what process I need to kill.

```
dan@natcoCo:/ $ ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:42 /sbin/init splash
root         2     0  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_gp]
root         4     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_par_gp]
root         8     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [mm_percpu_wq]
root         9     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:05 [ksoftirqd/0]
root        10     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:01:10 [rcu_sched]
root        11     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_bh]
root        12     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
root        13     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/0]
root        14     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/1]
root        15     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [migration/1]
root        16     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        19     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/2]
root        20     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [migration/2]
root        21     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
root        24     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [cpuhp/3]
root        25     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [migration/3]
root        26     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
root        29     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        30     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
root        34     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [khungtaskd]
root        35     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [oom_reaper]
root        36     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [writeback]
root        37     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [kcompactd0]
root        38     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [crypto]
root        39     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd]
root        41     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [watchdogd]
root        42     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [rpciod]
root        43     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u9:0-hci0]
root        44     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [xprtiod]
root        47     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:04 [kswapd0]
root        48     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [nfsiod]
root        59     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld]
root        60     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [iscsi_eh]
root        62     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [dwc_otg]
root        64     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [DWC Notificatio]
root        65     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:05 [vchiq-slot/0]
root        66     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:02 [vchiq-recy/0]
root        67     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [vchiq-sync/0]
root        68     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [vchiq-keep/0]
root        69     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [SMIO]
root        71     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [irq/38-brcmstb_]
root        72     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:17 [irq/39-mmc1]
root        74     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [irq/39-mmc0]
root        75     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [mmc_complete]
root        78     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:12 [jbd2/mmcblk0p7-]
root        79     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root        81     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root       111     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:06 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root       143     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:01 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root       209     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [cfg80211]
root       214     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [brcmf_wq/mmc1:0]
root       217     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:06 [brcmf_wdog/mmc1]
root       221     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [SMIO]
root       232     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [mmal-vchiq]
root       234     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:42 [v3d_bin]
root       235     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [mmal-vchiq]
root       236     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:42 [v3d_render]
root       237     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [v3d_tfu]
root       238     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [mmal-vchiq]
root       239     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [v3d_csd]
root       241     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [v3d_cache_clean]
message+   327     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:05 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --
avahi      334     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:01:45 avahi-daemon: running [natcoCo.l
root       344     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/udisks2/udisksd
nobody     347     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:51 /usr/sbin/thd --triggers /etc/tr
avahi      354   334  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 avahi-daemon: chroot helper
root       356     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/a
dan        364  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:18 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
root       367     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
root       374     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:01 /sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -s -O /r
root       378     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:03 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
root       385     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -b
root       396     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n -iNONE
root       402     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:15 /usr/sbin/rngd -r /dev/hwrng
ntp        480     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:24 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.
root       482     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --n
root       485     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unat
root       499     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/lightdm
root       523     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:02 wpa_supplicant -B -c/etc/wpa_sup
Debian-+   918     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/exim4 -bd -q30m
root       965     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/hciattach /dev/serial1 
root       966     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u9:2-hci0]
root       971     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
root       973     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/bluealsa
root       986     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [krfcommd]
dan       1003  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:06 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       1079  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:21 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
ken       1147     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
ken       1150  1147  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
ken       1170  1147  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session -
ken       1204  1147  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
ken       1209  1147  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/us
ken       1231     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -s
ken       1277  1147  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volum
ken       1281  1147  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-mo
ken       1285  1147  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-mo
ken       1290  1147  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volum
ken       1294  1147  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-goa-volume-mo
ken       1365  1204  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spaw
root      1372     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/mmcblk0p8-]
root      1373     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
ken       1378  1147  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
dan       1542  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:17 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
root      3390     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:12 /usr/sbin/nmbd --foreground --no
root      4172     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:02 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no
root      4174  4172  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no
root      4175  4172  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no
root      4176  4172  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/smbd --foreground --no
dan       4866  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:36 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
root      5266   499  0 Dec29 tty7     00:18:54 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :0 -seat seat
root      5315   499  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 lightdm --session-child 14 23
dan       5326     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
dan       5329  5326  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
dan       5340  5315  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:04 /usr/bin/lxsession -s LXDE-pi -e
dan       5349  5326  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --session -
dan       5374  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:10 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       5446  5719  1 Dec30 ?        00:13:28 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       5508  5340  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent x-session-man
dan       5518  5326  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
dan       5523  5326  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/us
dan       5534  5340  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:20 openbox --config-file /home/dan/
dan       5536  5340  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:01 lxpolkit
dan       5538  5340  0 Dec29 ?        00:01:39 lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
dan       5540  5340  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:26 pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
dan       5548     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/lib/raspi-config/cm
dan       5552     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -s
dan       5555  5548  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 xcompmgr -aR
dan       5586     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/menu-cache/menu-cached 
dan       5591  5326  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volum
dan       5597  5326  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-mo
dan       5601  5326  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-mo
dan       5606  5326  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volum
dan       5610  5326  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-goa-volume-mo
dan       5682  5518  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-trash --spaw
dan       5696  5538  1 Dec29 ?        00:52:59 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       5717  5696  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       5719  5717  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       5745  5696  1 Dec29 ?        00:38:15 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       5749  5696  0 Dec29 ?        00:10:22 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       5897  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:23 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       5909  5719  0 Dec29 ?        00:02:27 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       5941  5719  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:03 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       6017  5745  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       6075  5719  0 Dec29 ?        00:11:19 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       6092  5719  0 Dec29 ?        00:15:44 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       6308  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:42 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       6792  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:32 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       7097  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:04 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
root      7208     2  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:01 [kworker/2:2H-kblockd]
dan       7326  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:09 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       7471  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:22 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan       8941  5326  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
dan       8969  5540  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:03 gpicview /home/dan/2019-12-29-14
dan       8982  5540  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:04 gpicview /home/dan/2019-12-29-14
root      9491     2  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:06 [kworker/3:1H-kblockd]
root      9881     1  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-ta
root      9886  9881  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --s
mysql    10003  9886  0 Dec29 ?        00:03:04 /usr/sbin/mysqld --basedir=/usr 
root     10004  9886  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 logger -t mysqld -p daemon error
dan      12831  5719  0 08:16 ?        00:00:09 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      13405  5719  0 Dec29 ?        00:01:30 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      13419  5719  0 Dec29 ?        00:01:32 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      13721  5719  0 Dec29 ?        00:02:43 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
root     13797 32525  0 08:20 pts/2    00:00:00 sudo mysql_secure_installation
root     13802 13797  0 08:20 pts/2    00:00:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysql_secure_in
dan      13904  5719  0 08:25 ?        00:01:24 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      13933 26204  0 08:26 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
root     14028     2  0 08:32 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1-cgroup_destroy]
dan      14209  5518  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-network --sp
dan      14220  5518  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-smb-browse -
dan      14222  5326  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
dan      14236  5518  0 Dec29 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-dnssd --spaw
root     14881     2  0 08:56 ?        00:00:02 [kworker/0:1H-mmc_complete]
dan      16533  5719  7 09:25 ?        00:08:01 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      17777  5719  3 10:22 ?        00:01:49 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      17810  5719  0 10:22 ?        00:00:30 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
root     17821     2  0 10:22 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1H-kblockd]
dan      17822  5719  0 10:22 ?        00:00:12 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      18115  5719  0 10:28 ?        00:00:21 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      18130  5719  0 10:28 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
root     18146     2  0 10:29 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:2-events]
root     18190     1  0 10:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18191 18190  0 10:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18192 18190  0 10:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18193 18190  0 10:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18194 18190  0 10:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data 18195 18190  0 10:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root     18383     1  0 10:33 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/
www-data 18385 18383  0 10:33 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 18386 18383  0 10:33 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 18387 18383  0 10:33 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
www-data 18388 18383  0 10:33 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
root     18460     2  0 10:38 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u8:2-events_unbound]
root     19112     2  0 10:41 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:2H]
root     19205     2  0 10:53 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0-mm_percpu_wq]
root     19238     2  0 10:58 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/u8:1-events_unbound]
root     19243     2  0 10:58 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0-events_power_effici
root     19249     2  0 10:59 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:1H]
root     19283     2  0 11:05 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root     19292     2  0 11:05 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:2-mm_percpu_wq]
root     19300     2  0 11:07 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H-kblockd]
root     19303     2  0 11:08 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:1-events]
root     19371     2  0 11:09 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0-cgroup_destroy]
root     19377     2  0 11:10 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:1-events_freezable]
root     19387     2  0 11:12 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:2H]
root     19396     2  0 11:13 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:2-mm_percpu_wq]
root     19411     2  0 11:14 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0H]
dan      19417 13933  0 11:16 pts/3    00:00:00 ps -ef
dan      19563  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:10 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      20209  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:03:28 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      20260  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:13 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      21898  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:01:42 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      21937  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:27 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      21948  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:01 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      21962  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:01:52 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      23333  5719  1 Dec30 ?        00:16:12 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      23378  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:01:14 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      23499  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:29 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      24888  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:20 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
dan      26204  5538  0 Dec30 ?        00:01:20 lxterminal
dan      26210 26204  0 Dec30 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
dan      26741  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:33 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
root     28781     1  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:00 dbus-launch --autolaunch 9092ccb
root     28782     1  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --syslog-on
dan      32525 26204  0 Dec30 pts/2    00:00:00 bash
dan      32596  5719  0 Dec30 ?        00:00:14 /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromi
```

Comment: So you touched the file that explicitly warned you not to touch it? When you're first setting up the database, it generally will be set up without a password. You will need to set a password of course, but you need to do that using a "mysql" command. Have you checked `ps -ef` to see if it's running? If it is, halt it. Then run it with `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`. You should be able to login as "root" without a password, then set it within "mysql". Halt and restart normally.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.  I am not sure what process to kill so I posted the list that you suggested above.  Could you please guide me to the process that is getting in the way.

Comment: OK, you have two options. Either it is running, and you need to halt it, and the safest way to do that depends on your OS. Or it is not running, and you can skip that step. Rather than scanning a full "ps" listing, why don't you try using "grep"? The process in question will either be "mariadb" or "mysqld", so for the former, try: `ps -ef | grep maria`. If the only process that is returned is your "grep" command (which has "maria" on the command line), then the process is not running.

Answer (score 0):

The file you showed (/etc/mysql/debian.cnf) looks exactly the same on my system, and I have a working instrallation with a root password. It appears to be normal that the password line is empty.
Important note: only the root user is able to login to the mariadb root account.
To login, try `$ sudo mysql -uroot -p`
As mentioned before, try stopping the mysql process (in your list nr. 10003). 
I tried to write this as a comment, but my reputation wasn't high enough.